# Where should I use CSS preprocessors and where should I use style scoped?

Tags: css, vue.js

Vue.js support encapsulation of CSS to .vue files with the `<style scoped>` directive. I can't understand where I should use it, and where it's better to use CSS preprocessors like Stylus.

My idea that should be `site.css` with global styles and every single `.vue` files should have own styles (like colors of elements and other minor stuff). Am I right?

Comment: It's completely up to you and how you want to structure your project - there's no one true way. That said, the way you described is probably how I'd choose to do it too (although I'd probably use the same preprocessor on the global files too for consistency/the extra features).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not "either / or". You don't have to choose, the two features do different things and can be combined.

A **Preprocessor** like SCSS lets your write CSS with additional syntax features, like variables. This makes writing CSS easier. But in the end, you get normal CSS, and the selector rules come out with the same names as you wrote them.

The **scoped** feature does something very different: it takes the CSS (*after* the preprocessor has processed it) and adds a unique attribute selector to all rules *and* an attribute to all elements in your template. That makes this CSS work **only** for elements in this component.

Why is this useful? Because it prevents unwanted side-effects. You can write easy class names like "header" in your (S)CSS without having to worry about that maybe, some other component also uses this class name for something different and the style rules might conflict and overwrite each other. That cannot happen with `scoped`.

More info on that feature here:

http://vue-loader.vuejs.org/en/features/scoped-css.html

Comment: should I use site.css or it's better to put ever css in `scoped` component?

Comment: CSS as should be applied to all of the site is probably better done in a separate file like `site.css`

Answer (score 1):

You are in the right path. There is no right answer here. I tend to create a `base.styl` or `base.scss` that I then import in `app.vue`. I personally do not use `scoped` but more a modular css approach for the styles specific inside vue component files. i.e. `.componentname` as your root class, and then write your styles according to [smacss](https://smacss.com) or [bem](http://getbem.com) approach.

I suggest you keep consistency with the same css preprocessor across all components of your app.

Comment: I do this too. I have a `defs.scss` file which contains SCSS definitions only (no CSS rules) which I `@import` into every component's stylesheet.